# Format the cells of an output excel file in C++

Tags: c++, excel, csv

My question today isn't something of great importance, but is just something I've come across on some side projects for my friends.

One such friend wanted me to make a program to, basically, randomly store the integers 1-52 into 2 separate arrays for a game he likes.  From there the code reads through the arrays (one for each player essentially), determines which character pertains to the random number in that index, then exports it.  In the end you have all 52 characters divided evenly and randomly between both players (26 each), with no repeats.  The main program works fine, but I wanted to make it a bit better.

My question comes in with what I did to make it a bit easier to read.  Rather than simply export the information to a text file, I though such information would be better utilized as an Excel Spreadsheet for much more convenient editing purposes, as well as easily viewing the information as a table.  Once again, that's working fine.

However, a lot of the information exceeds the default size of the cells in the document.  Also, as a whole, the information would look much better with all the cells centered.  Instead of having to manually do this every time the program is run, I was wondering if there was a way to integrate those formating changes directly into the code itself, and if there is, is it done with relatively little effort?  Having to learn some crazy stuff just for some aesthetics on something I'm just building for a friend just isn't really worth it.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void exportToExcel(int[], int[], int);
string printChar(int[], int);
bool isPicked(int);

int pastRandoms[52];
ofstream outFile;

void main()
{
    const int CHAR_PER_PLAYER = 26;
    int random, player1[CHAR_PER_PLAYER], player2[CHAR_PER_PLAYER];
    string filename = "Roster.csv";
    outFile.open(filename);
    if (outFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "FAILED";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (short count = 0; count < 52; count++)
        pastRandoms[count] = 0;
    for (short count = 0; count < CHAR_PER_PLAYER; count++)
    {
        do
        {
            random = rand() % 52 + 1;
        } while (isPicked(random));
        player1[count] = random;
    }
    for (short count = 0; count < CHAR_PER_PLAYER; count++)
    {
        do
        {
            random = rand() % 52 + 1;
        } while (isPicked(random));
        player2[count] = random;
    }
    exportToExcel(player1, player2, CHAR_PER_PLAYER);
    outFile.close();
}

bool isPicked(int r)
{
    for (short c = 0; c < 52; c++)
        if (r == pastRandoms[c])
            return true;
    for (short c = 0; c < 52; c++)
    {
        if (pastRandoms[c] == 0)
        {
            pastRandoms[c] = r;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void exportToExcel(int p1[], int p2[], int n)
{
    outFile << ", Player 1, Player2" << endl;
    for (short c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        outFile << c + 1 << "," << printChar(p1, c) << "," << printChar(p2, c) << endl;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I left out the printChar function on purpose.  It's just a giant switch statement.  every number from 1-52 has it's own case and returns the appropriate name.  I felt it best to leave such a cumbersome function out of my initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to control the formatting of data imported into Microsoft Excel is to export this data as an `xls` or an `xlsx` file, and not a `csv` file, as you code is doing (there are also other formats that MS Excel knows how to import which include sufficient formatting metadata to control the appearance of imported data, but for all practical purposes the answer here is limited to `xls` and `xlsx`).

Microsoft Excel imports CSV-formatted data as is, into cells with default format, and you have no control over it. If you want to import something with formatted cells, you will have to generate an `xls` or an `xlsx` file.

Your question does not specify which operating system you're using. If you're using MS-Windows, I'm sure you will be able to quickly find, in Microsoft's extensive documentation, complete instructions for using the appropriate software libraries that generate `xlsx`-formatted files.

On Linux, the situation is a bit fuzzy. I know of several Perl modules that can easily crank out `xlsx` files, but no C++ libraries come to mind.

However, `xlsx` is just a gzipped collection of XML files, and there's plenty of documentation on the Intertubes (at least for the most part), of the internal format of `xlsx` files, and it shouldn't be too hard to write your own implementation. I did the same exact thing in Perl, a little while ago -- producing formatted `xlsx` files that were imported into Excel -- and it shouldn't take long to crank out the same thing in C++.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I had been purposely avoiding anything besides csv since I already knew how to work with it.  However, I am using MS-Windows, so finding the correct implementation for what I want shouldn't be too difficult.  I just wanted to avoid the extra work if at all possible.  Once again, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

every thing that you save in .csv file just is text structure.
.csv files are text-type (no random files) for example if you save bellow text in .csv file :

ali; reza; hamid; /n

saeed; mohammad; hosain;

then when you open top file in excel, its as a table with 2 rows and 3 columns and you cant save math arithmetics (expressions) directly in real form, for example when you save '= 10 + 2' in a cell of .csv file, it save as '12' in file (no '= 10 + 2')! you cant define a format for a cell in a .csv file, because .csv files stores as text files.

if you want create .xlsx files and use of thats flexabilities or use of cell formats, you must use of excel classes and functions in your program!

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I had been purposely avoiding anything besides csv since I already knew how to work with it.  However, finding the correct implementation for what I want shouldn't be too difficult.  I just wanted to avoid the extra work if at all possible.  Once again, thanks for the info!